# React-native: Invariant Violation: "main" has not been registered

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I had this errors with do any thing application was running correct, close the application and open it and that what happened without change Name of application,
I tried to remove Node-modules and reinstall it close vs code and open it again
nothing happen

First Error:
Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:

1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
   See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.

second error:
Invariant Violation: "main" has not been registered. This can happen if:

- Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.
- A module failed to load due to an error and `AppRegistry.registerComponent` wasn't called.

Comment: Please post your Code. This is the reason: `Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component`. I ran into this error multiple times. Its easy to fix. But I can't remember without an example.

Comment: Did you try the steps at the link in the error message